# How can I update the File System after creating a folder programmatically?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, securityexception

I already created a folder in android grammatically but it doesn't show in File Explorer while device connected through USB cable.

Below is a piece of source code that i used to scan File system but it doesn't work. It giving error permission denial (Security Exception)

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()).getAbsolutePath()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                        }
                    });
                }
```

I'm using Android device that has Android 7.0 (OS). Can you help me out from this problem?

Comment: Why are you using both sendBroadCast and MediaScannerConnection?

Comment: Just use MediaScannerConnection only

Comment: Below Android 4.4, sendBroadcast is working perfectly...that's why

Comment: For <= 4.4 use BroadCast, more than that use MediaScannerConnection, will solve your problem

Comment: Should i have to add source code onScanCompleted method to update File system?

Comment: By calling scanFile method you are updating fileSystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

        } else {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()).getAbsolutePath()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                  //No need to call anything here
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Let me know if it helps you @Shail

Comment: It is not working on Nougat. If you have any reference for that, let me know.

Comment: Can you help me?